# Appium did not support chrome browser version 76

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium

Appium version 1.14.1 did not support chrome browser latest version 76 and higher.
I tried to find so many possible solutions but still, I'm not able to find any solution about this and finally, somehow I manage to downgrade chrome version in my mobile device and test run successfully.
I'm attaching an image of the error log here for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying the desired chromedriver version during Appium installation:

```
npm install appium --chromedriver-version="76.0.3809.68"
```

For more information and troubleshooting tips see:

- [Using ChromeDriver](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/)
- [ChromeDriver on Android](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/ChromeDriver+on+Android)
- [appium-chromedriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-chromedriver)